# Можно ли в VS 2012 посмотреть ассемблерный код?

Tags: ассемблер, компилятор, visual-studio-2012, дизассемблирование

Добрый день!
Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в VS 2012 pro посмотреть ассемблерный код написанной программки? Или только дизассемблировать каждую программу вручную?
Где-то слышала, что можно заставить компилятор создавать сразу не объектный код а ассемблерный. В настройках не нашла.

*Заранее спасибо)
И прощу прощения за дурацкий вопрос)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Output Files > Assembler output

Comment: @nitrocaster Извините, что через пару лет :), но интересует почти тот же вопрос - только как это получить из командной строки и нет ли дизассемблера объектных файлов командной строки?..

Comment: Вот так, например: `cl /FAs main.cpp`